# How can we implement a simple asynchronous iterator in python that returns integers 1 to 10, each with a second of waiting time? ( In Python 3.10 )

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.10

I want to implement a simple python program in python 3.10, that will print integers 1 to 10 with one second of waiting time between each print(number).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [`for` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep).

Comment: `import time
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)`